# JavaScript if/else Statement Input Data

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Please help me, I am studying on my own and need help, I want to create an "JavaScript else if statement" but this doesn't work.

Who wants to make input

// If "x" is greater than or equal to 1 and "x" is less than 10, and "y" is equal to 100, output "+"

// If "x" is greater than or equal to 11 and "x" is less than 100, and "y" is equal to 100, output "++"

// If "x" is greater than or equal to 1 and "x" is less than 10, and "y" is equal to 1, output "+++"

// If "x" is greater than or equal to 10, and "y" is equal to 1, output "++++"

The code that I tried to make, below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please Help:</p>

<input id="numb1" type="text">
<input id="numb2" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="tes"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x, y, text;

  x = document.getElementById("numb1").value;
  y = document.getElementById("numb2").value;
   
  if (x > 1 || x < 10 || y == 100) {
    text = "+";
  } else if (x > 11 || x < 100 || y == 100) {
    text = "++";
  } else if (x > 1 || x < 10 || y == 1) {
    text = "+++";
  } else if (x > 10 || y == 1) {
    text = "++++";
  }
  document.getElementById("tes").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every time your instructions say "and", you have written the `||` logical 'or' test when you should use the `&&` logical 'and' test.

Comment: Like @jarmod said, you're using the wrong operator in most places: 'and' is `&&`, not `||`. Additionally, for the 'is equal to' test, I suggest you use `===` , not `==` - this way, you can catch type errors too.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for the help, and the answer is very valuable for me, to continue to understand my writing errors

Comment: @DeoluA Thanks, I'll try to understand and fix it

Comment: @atlm no worries. This link should help explain some: https://www.guru99.com/difference-equality-strict-operator-javascript.html . All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full Working Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please Help:</p>

<input id="numb1" type="text">
<input id="numb2" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="tes"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x, y, text;

  x = document.getElementById("numb1").value;
  y = document.getElementById("numb2").value;
   
  if (x >= 1 && x < 10 && y == 100) {
    text = "+";
  } else if (x >= 11 && x < 100 && y == 100) {
    text = "++";
  } else if (x >= 1 && x < 10 && y == 1) {
    text = "+++";
  } else if (x >= 10 && y == 1) {
    text = "++++";
  }
  document.getElementById("tes").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Explanation:**

You were using `||` which means or in logical statements, where you meant to use `&&` to represent and.

Furthermore, when using logical statements, more than or equal to would be represented by `>=` and not `>`.

What you used:

```
if (x > 1 || x < 10 || y == 100) {
  text = "+";
} else if (x > 11 || x < 100 || y == 100) {
  text = "++";
} else if (x > 1 || x < 10 || y == 1) {
  text = "+++";
} else if (x > 10 || y == 1) {
  text = "++++";
}
```

What you were supposed to use:

```
if (x >= 1 && x < 10 && y == 100) {
  text = "+";
} else if (x >= 11 && x < 100 && y == 100) {
  text = "++";
} else if (x >= 1 && x < 10 && y == 1) {
  text = "+++";
} else if (x >= 10 && y == 1) {
  text = "++++";
}
```

To learn more about JavaScript Operators and Comparison Logical Operators (i.e. `||`, `&&`, `>`, `>=`, `==` or `!=`), visit:

> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp

**Recommended changes to code:**

I would strongly recommend adding an `else` statement to the conditional statement in you code, as then if all other conditions don't apply there will be a back-up, and your code will not error out and print out `undefined`.

Comment: Wow, I'm starting to understand, I have to read this material, thank you for the help and answer.

Answer (score 0):

**first:** the `OR - ||` opartor returns true even if only one of the expression in is both sides are true. the `AND - &&` operator returns true only if both of them are true, and this is what you are looking for.
so you have to replece all the `OR` opartors with `AND` operators.

**second:** to check if a value is greater than or equal to another value, you have to combine both operators `>` and `=` together.

```
if (x >= 1 && x < 10 && y == 100) {
    text = "+";
  } else if (x >= 11 && x < 100 && y == 100) {
    text = "++";
  } else if (x >= 1 && x < 10 && y == 1) {
    text = "+++";
  } else if (x >= 10 && y == 1) {
    text = "++++";
  }
```

Comment: Please include an explanation.

Comment: @Aplet123 it's OK now?

Comment: You just explained what you did, not **why** you did what you did, which means OP still won't learn where he went wrong.

Comment: I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: @yochanansheinberger Thank you, although it is not explained in detail, I will try to understand it,